# Oracle Privilege - User can create table but cannot write rows

Tags: oracle, permissions

A user has been configured on Oracle.  Via this user, I can create an ODBC connection and an OCI connection, and these both test fine in Win10.  Using Alteryx with the ODBC and OCI connection, we try to write data to a new table.

The table is created and appears in PL/SQL with the expected column names.  However, the rows are never written and the connection just hangs at this point.

What could be wrong?  I am not an Oracle Admin

Comment: Did you commit?

Comment: In MSSQL, you don't need to commit - data is just written.  Is there a way to make Oracle just write the records, and not need a terminating commit?

Comment: Following up: Oracle was an OCI - Oracle Cloud Instance.  The ODBC was reporting that it had written records after COMMIT was appended, but it was actually failing.  Only by switching to an OCI connection were we able to write data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments you were expecting oracle to commit without executing "commit" command explicitly. It's not enabled by default in oracle so you have to turn it on.

It's not possible to turn this on for the database, but on client apps only.

E.g. "set autocommit on" command in SQL Plus.

So you need to check docs for the client application you're connected with (presumably Alteryx is the one). It might have such a feature.

Comment: Alteryx can issue pre and post SQL statements around the Insert statements.  I assume I could add SET AUTOCOMMIT ON as a pre SQL, or add COMMIT as a post SQL, and either of these might work.  Will try, and revert...

Comment: The "set autocommit on" command is for sql plus - this is another client app to get connected to oracle, So, it might be differ from Alteryx. But if you can issue POST commands, what stops you from issuing a "commit"

Comment: Nothing is stopping us from trying COMMIT - we will try this out.  I am a consultant working remotely, so I have asked the client to try this out, via email, so there will be a delay.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveHibbert no probs, let me know if you need further help

Comment: See above, main comment, but worth saying here;  This was actually a problem with the ODBC connection - it is not appropriate for OCI, even though it appears to work.  Many thanks to @ekochergin for the help with this.